# Plotting with errorbars in Python

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, errorbar

I have a list, the form is [[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)], [...], [...]]

`[[(10.0, -1.0), (7.0, 0.05889647076017157), (13.0, 0.47096776983628086)], [(10.5, -1.0), (13.0, 0.07080679131269396), (7.5, 0.16547229577841294)], [(11.0, -1.0), (8.0, 0.27471205881135075), (13.5, 0.682988382311833)]]`

I would like to extract the first index in tuples from the list.

For example, the list above would be -> `[[(10.0), (7.0), (13.0)], [(10.5), (13.0), (7.5)], [(11.0), (8.0), (13.5)]]` (The form: [[(x1), (x2), (x3)], [(x4), (x5), (x6)], [(x7), (x8), (x9)]]

and then turn into a plot with errorbars. (The first value in the tuples would be the main values, and other two values would be errors)

This is what I am trying to get:

[image]

How can I do this? I can't find any similar example online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list out in this way:

```
vals = [[i[0] for i in tup] for tup in lst ]
vals

[[10.0, 7.0, 13.0], [10.5, 13.0, 7.5], [11.0, 8.0, 13.5]]
```

To plot, it's easier to have it in a np matrix, and sorted because the error bar function needs the length as input and not the coordinate:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals = np.sort(np.array(vals))
vals[:,[0,2]] = vals[:,[0,2]] - vals[:,1].reshape(-1,1)
vals

array([[-3. , 10. ,  3. ],
       [-3. , 10.5,  2.5],
       [-3. , 11. ,  2.5]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.errorbar(vals[:,1], vals[:,1], yerr=[-vals[:,0],vals[:,2]], fmt='o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [[(10.0, -1.0), (7.0, 0.05889647076017157), (13.0, 0.47096776983628086)], [(10.5, -1.0), (13.0, 0.07080679131269396), (7.5, 0.16547229577841294)], [(11.0, -1.0), (8.0, 0.27471205881135075), (13.5, 0.682988382311833)]]

plt.boxplot([[j[0] for j in i] for i in x])
```